# Sort list of lists based on the sum of each nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, function, sorting

I am new to python and I am trying to create a function that accepts as input a list of lists of integers and returns a sorted version of that list, sorted by the sum of the integers in each sub-list. Below is the code I have thus far. Any suggestions would be great.

```
def sort_nested_lists (user_list):
for list in user_list
    x = sum(user_list))
    x = sorted( user_list)
    return x
print sort_nested_lists
```

Here is my new code:

```
user_list = raw_input("Please enter a list of integers: ")
def sort_nested_lists(user_list):
  return sorted(user_list,key = sum)
print sort_nested_lists
```

Now I get the error:

Please enter a list of integers: [[5,2,7,5],[8,2,6,1],[3,1,8,9,5]]

Any additional help would be great!

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to make it so complicated. Simply use the following *one-liner*:

```
return sorted(user_list,key=sum)
```

That's all. When you specify a `key`, `sorted(..)` will compare two elements based on the given function it **applies** to elements in the `user_list`. So here it will compare two lists based on the sum of their elements.

Comment: Interesting thanks for the input! If I am trying to use function parameters for the problem any ideas on why the below code will not execute?                       def sort_nested_lists(user_list):
   return sorted(user_list,key = sum)
print sort_nested_lists

Comment: @AvSmith Probably because you are not calling the function, for making a call to the function, you have to do `sort_nested_lists(your_list)`. If you are calling it right, you have to be more specific explaining *the code is **NOT** executing* by giving error message, unexpected output, etc

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you may call the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function with *key* as `sum`

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 6, 3], [2,1,0], [10, 3, 9]]
>>> sorted(my_list, key=sum)
[[2, 1, 0], [1, 6, 3], [10, 3, 9]]
```

The resultant list will be sorted in increasing order based on the sum of integers in the sub-lists